# undo ntfs file encryption

Tags: encryption, ntfs

I have a pc with some encrypted file on it (shown in green) these files were created and encrypted by a user who has since then been removed from windows. I can see the files, but when I click on them nog preview (these are jpg files) is shown and I cannot open or copy them.

From what I've read on http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=308993 there seems to be no solution for this problem unless one has exported their certificate or public/private key, wich this user did not.

Anyone here have or know of a solution for this ?

thanks,
Jurjen.

Answer (score 3):

Whole point of encryption is not being able to decrypt data without key. If there is no encryption key exported for that user, there is no decrypting.

Answer (score 1):

**[EFS Key](http://www.lostpassword.com/efs.htm)** $195

**[Advanced EFS Data Recovery](http://www.elcomsoft.com/aefsdr.html)** from $149

**[WinHex](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/index-m.html)** from $55

Microsoft have their own recovery program (reccerts.exe), only available via payed support.